# Creating XML AUTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have 6 tables from which I want to create an XML output.  They need to be nested in the order 1,2,2,3,4,2 (Patient, Referral, Referral Type, Appointment, Activity, GP of Patient)  Is this possible using XML AUTO ELEMENTS?  I have done it using XML EXPLICIT, but AUTO would be a preferred method as we have trouble with the explicit table and NULL values.
The tables used are:

```
CREATE TABLE Header (ReportStartDate varchar(800), ExtractDate varchar(800))
CREATE TABLE Patient (PatientID varchar(800), DateOfBirth varchar(800)) 
CREATE TABLE Referral (ReferralID varchar(800), PatientID varchar(800))
CREATE TABLE Appointment (AppointmentID varchar(800), ReferralID varchar(800))
CREATE TABLE Activity (ActivityID varchar(800),AppointmentID varchar(800))
CREATE TABLE MedHistory (MedHistoryID varchar(800), ActivityID varchar(800))
CREATE TABLE Gp (GpID varchar(800), PatientID varchar(800))
CREATE TABLE  StaffHistory (StaffHistoryID varchar(800))
```

The tables need to be in this order.  Header is a Root table, Patient, Referral, Appointment, and Activity are nested.  MedHistory is nested at Activity Level, GP Inside Patient and the Staff History at the end, not nested.  Is this possible?
Sorry - This is the output I need:

```
<Header>
    <ReportStartDate>2017-02-02</ReportStartDate>
    <ExtractDate>2018-08-16</ExtractDate>
    <Patient>
        <PatientID>123456</PatientID>
        <DateOfBirth>1984-11-15</DateOfBirth>
        <Referral>
            <ReferralID>ABC</ReferralID>
            <PatientID>123456</PatientID>
            <Appointment>
                <AppointmentID>XYZ</AppointmentID>
                <ReferralID>ABC</ReferralID>
                <Activity>
                    <ActivityID>MNL</ActivityID>
                    <AppointmentID>XYZ</AppointmentID>
                /Activity
                <MedHistory>
                    <MedHistoryID>789</MedHistoryID>
                    <ActivityID>MNL</ActivityID>
                </MedHistory>
            </Appointment>
        </Referral>
        <Gp>
            <GpID>654</GpID>
            <PatientID>123456>
        </Gp>
    </Patient>
    <Patient>
        <PatientID>Z765883</PatientID>
        <DateOfBirth>1952-02-06</DateOfBirth>
        <Referral>
            <ReferralID>N66</ReferralID>
            <PatientID>Z765883</PatientID>
            <Appointment>
                <AppointmentID>479</AppointmentID>
                <ReferralID>N66</ReferralID>
                <Activity>
                    <ActivityID>G33</ActivityID>
                    <AppointmentID>479</AppointmentID>
                /Activity
                <MedHistory>
                    <MedHistoryID>F45</MedHistoryID>
                    <ActivityID>G33</ActivityID>
                </MedHistory>
            </Appointment>
        </Referral>
        <Gp>
            <GpID>PGF</GpID>
            <PatientID>Z765883>
        </Gp>
    </Patient>
    <StaffHistory>
        <StaffHistoryID>JHI</StaffHistoryID>
</Header>
```

Comment: The `AUTO` is short for "automatic", meaning you get little to no control over the output in exchange for a simpler syntax. The most common mode is actually `PATH`, giving you most if not all necessary control over the output without the clumsy rowset requirements of `EXPLICIT`. If you can give the table structure and the desired output, we can almost certainly provide a query to get what you want.

Comment: Incidentally, from the question I assume this is about SQL Server, since I'm not aware of another RDBMS with the same modes. If I'm right, please tag it accordingly (`sql-server`) so more people can find it.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen.  The structure of the tables is as follows (and I hope I'm not simplifying it too much) Header.ReportStartDate, Header.ExtractionDate      Patient.PatientID, Patient.DateOfBirth  Referral.PatientID, Referral.ReferralID    Appointment.AppointmentID, Appointment.ReferralID    Activity.ActivityID, Activity.AppointmentID     MedicalHistory.MedicalHistoryID, MedicalHistory.ActivityID  Gp.GpID  Gp.PatientID  StaffHistory.StaffHistoryID

Comment: To add more details to your question, you can edit it using the "edit" link under it; comments are not a good place because of their transient nature, length limits and poor formatting. If you're adding table structures, what helps most is presenting them in the form of `CREATE TABLE` statements, since people will be able to run this directly on their machines. Simplifying to only the things necessary for the question (but no further) is a great idea.

Comment: You may also want to read up on [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can use indentation to mark code samples. Also, your question's still missing the desired output in the form of what the XML should look like (some sample data would help with that too). [This article](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) has some good tips on SQL questions in general.

Comment: As @JeroenMostert said, the answer is "no it is not possible" so instead use `FOR XML PATH`. Good luck.